# Unity3d, Parse.com throw exception, (System.AggregateException)

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine, aggregateexception

so i'm trying to use parse.com in my unity project, it was all working fine until i added a new column in my user database. It throw exception every time i tried to access my currentUser.

In the error shown below, it mentioned that something goes wrong at line 20 of my login.cs script, however, line 20 of this script is called in both my login scene and my menu scene, but the exception is only thrown in menu scene, not when in login scene.

When i'm trying to run the scene, it says

```
AggregateException: Exception of type 'System.AggregateException' was thrown.
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait ()
Parse.ParseUser.get_CurrentUser ()
login.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/login.cs:20)
```

And Here's some of my code arround line 20:

```
string currentSceneName = SceneManager.GetActiveScene ().name;
if ((ParseUser.CurrentUser != null) && (currentSceneName != headToScene)) {
  SceneManager.LoadScene (headToScene);
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!